# Special chars in Laravel .env file

Tags: laravel, centos, environment-variables

I'm having troubles using special chars in values of a Laravel .env file.
For example:

```
DB_PASSWORD=some#secret
```

Now the `env('DB_PASSWORD')` is just 'some'

Is there a way to escape characters or some other method to use values like this in the .env file?

In case it makes a difference, my server is running on CentOS 8.2.2004

UPDATE: Forget the whole thing. It turned out it was a different issue altogether. Answer below is correct on the actual question though.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`#` is for commenting in a `.env` file. If you want to use `#` as a value, you need to wrap it in `"`:

```
DB_PASSWORD='some#secret'
```